# Can we use my python code in Android Studio?

Tags: python, android, android-studio

I have a project and I am making this with python. But I really want to do this for mobile, so can  I use my python code in Adroid studio ?

I mean can we entegrate it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just use a framework like PyMob.

http://www.pyzia.com/

Though note that it's probably much more worth your time to just learn Java than having to deal with errors and reduction in functionality that you'll get from not using the native language.